# Ruby on Rails Tutorial chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am confused by the addition of [:session] to params. It also seems to break my website. Can someone please explain what this does for me?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Error message:

1) Authentication signin with invalid information
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Sign in" }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in`create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:18:in`block (4 levels) in '

## EDIT 8/2

I believe the problem is related to a switch from form_for to form_tag. I lost the reference to sessions in the switch because I could not figure out how to properly include it. If anyone has any advice on this issue it would be most appreciated. I am wondering if there is a practical reason for wanting it to be params[:session][:email] instead or is it just for organization?

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>

      <%= label_tag :email %>
      <%= text_field_tag :email %>

      <%= label_tag :password %>
      <%= password_field_tag :password %>

      <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you send your app/sessions/create.html.erb please? You can also add `puts params` at the top of your create action and see us the result.

Comment: I assume you are referring to my new.html.erb which is now included.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the [:session] brackets, that worked for me

Comment: This does work, and has led me to figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

It brakes your code 'cos the params[:session] is nil I think and you trying to get [:email] from nil, what ofcourse should cause the exception. There should be some code in tutorial that defines params[:session] hash. Try to look better.
To make your code stable you have to be sure that params[:session] is always defined or try to use ternar function params[:session] ? params[:session][:email] : ''

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this in your view :

```
<%= form_for :session, :url => sessions_path do %>

  <%= label_tag :email %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email %>

  <%= label_tag :password %>
  <%= password_field_tag :password %>

  <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

form_tag generate just an HTML form tag and form_for is used to describe something. All the inputs for a field of a form create with form_for will have a name like this : `user_session[email]`. So, when you submit the form, in your controller, you will have this : `params[:user_session][:email]`.

Comment: The reason to use form_tag instead of form_for was so that the database was not involved, correct? Why should I switch back to form_for? What advantage do I get from the nested hashes?

Comment: form_tag generate just an HTML form tag and form for is used to describe something. All the inputs for a field of a form create with `form_for` will have a name like this : `user[login]`. So, when you submit the form, in your controller, you will have this : `params[:user][:login]`